# I did npm install html5-boilerplate, what does means in README.md 'pull'?

Tags: html5boilerplate

**1. Summarize the problem**

With this project: **html5-boilerplate**, is there a **README** or **getting started guide anywhere?**

I did: **`$npm install html5-boilerplate`** and setup an IDE project, **at this point how do I proceed?**

I see **`node_modules`**.

**Where is the template?**

Do I copy files from somewhere to somewhere?  Is this not what the **$npm install is supposed to do?** (copy files from somewhere to my local directory, that is then a template I can use?)

Is there a way, from within the library directory: **`node_modules/`** to run a command that would start a webserver to see the template?

Is this typically done? (run a command within **`node_modules/`** to run a webserver?  This is not typically done, run commands with a library directory.

Am I supposed to... I don't even know what to ask, how to proceed at this point.

I have a **`node_modules/`** directory, and a **`package-lock.json`* file from the install,

**what would one normally do next? and next? to:**

1. get a usable HTML5 template
2. do a build (build - whatever is needed to populate a `/dist/` directory
3. and then run something/anything to start a web server to see the template?

Sincerely,

**2. Provide background including what you've already tried**

1. I did **`npm install html5-boilerplate`**
2. I read the **README.md**,
3. and then went to the website, and could not find a getting started guide

I'm not sure what *pull from the node_modules what you need* means.  What action would I take, and in what form to 'pull'?

If I discover what **pull** means, how do I know what I need, what I don't?  I just want a **minimal HTML5 template**.

Are there things provided in templates that are not needed? if so **why?**

**3. Show some code**

I am trying to use a **`template`**, but I don't see a template.

I see a **`node_modules/`** directory (I have a directory that contains a library), and not sure if I should then:

1. go create a template
2. and somehow do an import, or include in the files I create, a reference to files under here.

**4. Describe expected and actual results including any error messages**

I am expecting to:

1. run a command that would fetch some files, that is the **template**
2. see a getting started doc that would then provide me with a command to run
3. the command would start a web server, and print to the console the URL to goto in a web browser (with regards to a HTML5 template)

instead, I fetched a library directory: **node_modules/** with no explanation on how to use the library, and the template is missing.

**Just those three things** I am expecting with any web template provided.

Answer (score 0):

We'll clarify some of the documentation. This is a weird area for the project as `npm install html5-boilerplate` isn't ever going to be the best way to get the project, to be honest. We added support for npm and spent a few weeks taking back control of the npm package because it was requested that we keep it up to date and we saw the need to ensure that the package hosted on npm was under our control. We suggest downloading the files from the site or checking out the project from Github and working with the files directly. HTML5 Boilerplate, in a lot of ways, is something you work with *before* git or npm is in play. It's meant to be a foundation. The only markup in the file visible to end users is

```
  <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
```

As for your specific case, running `npm install` copies a set of static files to your node_modules folder. You will find the entirety of the project inside `node_modules/html5-boilerplate/dist/`

[image: h5bp directory structure in an npm install]

If you want to see the file, you don't need to run a web server, you can just click on index.html and it will run just fine in the browser. As for what "pull" means in the readme, it simply means to copy whatever files you need from that folder. It doesn't refer to a command to run.